# Docker cannot remove all images

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

i'm using **Docker Desktop for Windows**. When I try to remove all of my images by this command:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

I got this error message in command prompt:

> unknown shorthand flag: 'q' in -q)

I'm running **Docker** on Window 10 Pro

Comment: which version of docker is it? you can find out by running `docker version`. Also try replacing the `-q` param with `--quiet`.

Comment: If you want to get rid of all unused stuff, `docker system prune` might come handy.

Answer (score 5):

Syntax is unix specific, so you change your command for Windows and you'll need to run the whole command in PowerShell or CMD.

remove containers:

```
powershell "docker ps -a -q | foreach-object { $i = $PSItem.ToString(); $cmd = 'docker'; & $cmd 'rm' '-f' $i }"
```

remove images:

```
powershell "docker images -a -q | foreach-object { $i = $PSItem.ToString(); $cmd = 'docker'; & $cmd 'rmi' '-f' $i }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but if you are on Windows switch from the cmd to PowerShell. cmd is misinterpreting some commands and tries to attach the -q to the outter rmi command.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [docker system prune -a](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) or [docker image prune -a](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/) commands to delete any unused or dangling images.

Answer (score 0):

Look at similar [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/155). The syntax you are using is unix specific `docker rmi $(command)`. This is called [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and probably will not work in windows.

Answer (score 0):

In the windows, you should windows command.

In powershell, it'll be something like:

```
docker images -a -q | foreach-object { $i = $PSItem.ToString(); $cmd = "docker"; & $cmd "rmi" $i }
```

Where

> docker images -a -q

gets the IDs of all images (including intermediate), and

> foreach-object { $i = $PSItem.ToString(); $cmd = "docker"; & $cmd "rmi" $i }

delete them one-by-one

Comment: "'foreach-object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. " from command line

Comment: are u running from powershell?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bash shell syntax which would work on Linux installs of docker. To get it to work on Windows, try installing the bash shell on Windows and running it from inside that shell. The Windows command prompt and powershell won't understand that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Powershell, it is easy.

Following command shows all images:

> docker -a -q

outputs this:

```
PS C:\Users\UserName> docker images -a -q
86fa138dd93d
7c3a8b83a719
6636e7059d8d
```

then, for each image do

> docker rmi ##########

Where ##### is the image id

Comment: This is a very inefficient solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

Save this in docker-clear.bat and execute to clear containers, images, unused data and volumes

```
@echo off
REM Clear all the containers
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker ps -aq') DO docker stop %%i && docker rm %%i
REM Clear all the images
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker images --format "{{.ID}}"') DO docker rmi %%i -f
REM Clear unused data
docker system prune -f
REM Clear all volumes
docker volume prune -f
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `-a`. To delete all the images, use this:

```
docker image prune -a -f
```

And remember that you have to remove all the associated containers before removing all the images.

To delete all containers in use:

```
docker container prune -f
```

Comment: @kaki gadol, `docker image prune -a -f` works like a charm on WIndows, but you need to first stop `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` and remove `docker container prune -f` all containers